# Opening a web page from a flash (AS3) sending POST vars

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, post

I want to open a web page on the same tab when the user clicks a movieclip. I'm using this method:

```
var url:String = "http://www.google.com";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
try {
  navigateToURL(request);
} catch (e:Error) {
  trace("Error occurred!");
}
```

But I have no idea of how to open it sending POST vars. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, by specifying POST as the method on URLRequest, and using flash.net.URLVariables for the vars. This is the example from the documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;

    public class URLRequest_method extends Sprite {

        public function URLRequest_method() {
            var url:String = "http://www.[yourDomain].com/application.jsp";
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            variables.exampleSessionId = new Date().getTime();
            variables.exampleUserLabel = "guest";
            request.data = variables;
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            navigateToURL(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason the vars were send using GET instead of POST, any idea?

Comment: Even if you do request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST? I'v read somewhere that executing code like the above from the Flash IDE will always use GET, but POST will work when running in a browser. Also, there used to be (and maybe still is) a strange bug that using the string "POST" would work, but not the URLRequestMethod.POST constant. So you could try request.method = "POST" instead of request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to "sub-question" above:

> *for some reason the vars were send using GET instead of POST, any
>   idea?*

That post [AS3 POST Request sending as a GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557264/as3-post-request-sending-as-a-get) may help if you are stumble upon this post like me.
Basic idea is: don't let the **request.data** goes empty/null. Just add something "dummy" or "unobtrusive" (from the server's point of view) like **request.data = "\r\n"**; this should prevent flash runtime overwrite your "POST" request with a "GET". It worked for me (thanks to my serverside app. was enough robust to handle nicely of which querystrings that starts with an empty parameter has an empty key and an empty value).

Answer (score 0):

If running in Flash Player and the referenced form has no body, Flash Player automatically uses a GET operation, even if the method is set to URLRequestMethod.POST. For this reason, it is recommended to always include a "dummy" body to ensure that the correct method is used.